# Monitoring zabbix server (itself) externally

Tags: monitoring, monit, zabbix, system-monitoring

I have some infrastructure (servers, switches etc) monitored by a Zabbix server, setup to alert in case of issues; so far so good.  But what if the Zabbix server itself (or any of the underlying infra) experiences a problem?

One idea would be to publish some sort of heartbeat, which can be monitored by an external system.  I'm thinking to use the Zabbix API (probably using py-zabbix) to expose this over http and have it monitored using smth like [monitor.us](http://monitor.us).

Before I take the plunge, I can't help wondering if something *simple* already exists to cover this?  Or is this even a good approach?  Would [monit](https://mmonit.com/monit/) be a better approach compared to a custom Python script? (not sure this passes the "simplicity" test)...

Comment: Note that Zabbix is able to monitor itself using internal checks, please see https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.4/manual/config/items/itemtypes/internal .

Comment: Fair enough but what if Zabbix (or the box on which it runs) crashes (I suppose we could have a 2nd server for HA) or if something goes wrong on the network and the Zabbix server becomes isolated?

Comment: If Zabbix server crashes, then, of course, it will not be able to monitor itself. For this reason, you should probably consider external monitoring, as your own question and the current answer suggest. Still, internal checks are a good way of monitoring Zabbix server health, as long as it is running and connected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here's what I ended up doing:

1. Wrote a fairly simple Python script which uses [pyzabbix](https://github.com/lukecyca/pyzabbix/wiki) to interrogate Zabbix for the set of "triggers" currently failing (see snippet below).  This runs periodically on a background Thread (so it has to be thread-safe).
2. I used [web.py](http://webpy.org/) to expose this to the external monitoring system.

There was an unexpected hiccup: the Zabbix API still responds even if the Zabbix server is down and there is no way to interrogate the status of the server - which was the main thing I wanted to monitor.  Thankfully a [patch exists](https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBXNEXT-1031) to allow such server status queries.

Here is the code to query the set of failing Zabbix triggers (adapted from [an example which comes with pyzabbix](https://github.com/lukecyca/pyzabbix/blob/master/examples/current_issues.py)).  If you need the code for the full monitor, please ask in a comment and I'll post it on github.

```
def __query_unacked_triggers(self):
    """ queries for currently tripped _triggers which haven't been acked """
    return self._zapi.trigger.get(
        only_true = 1,
        filter = { 'value': 1 },
        skipDependent = 1,
        monitored = 1,
        active = 1,
        output = 'extend',
        expandDescription = 1,
        expandData = 'host',
        withLastEventUnacknowledged = 1,
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

External heart beats is the way to go.

I am not aware of any such tools, I have my own for the monitoring system I use. Just make sure that it is a heart beat and not a failure report. Eg. you always report that everything is ok and when the monitoring system does not receive your heartbeat for a longer period then it should let you know.

Comment: Thanks Florin; what about the approach to implement/expose those: write my own Python script of use smth existing?

Comment: I am not aware of any such tools, I have my own for the monitoring system I use. Just make sure that it is a heart beat and not a failure report. Eg. you always report that everything is ok and when the monitoring system does not receive your heartbeat for a longer period then it should let you know. I will add this to the answer as well.

Comment: Here is what I have done.. Create a small AWS public cloud instance with a python script that sits there bound to a port. It accepts connections and then sets a last seen heartbeat.. If the last heartbeat is over 5 minutes old send a notification to pagerduty via their API